I have made a home domain using dnsmasq. and cannot successfully redirect to a 2nd server:
I have set up a home dns server using dnsmasq, and have created the domain 'home'.
I have an apache2 server on 10.1.1.170:80  and a nextcloud snap server on 10.1.1.170:82.
The result of
lslookup nextcloud.home 

is
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   nextcloud.home
Address: 10.1.1.170

and I have a nextcloud.conf file configured as below.
ServerName nextcloud.home
<VirtualHost *:80>
 
    ServerAlias www.nextcloud.home

    ProxyPass / http://10.1.1.170:82/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.1.170:82/

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost> 

What I expect to happen is that Apache will present the nextcloud server when the url is
http://nextcloud.home. Google Gemini tells me have set everything up OK, but it has lied to me before. Can somebody advise me what more would make everything work?  Thanks.
